# Retornar valores entre horas e minutos - PostGres SQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, select, data

creio que seja uma dúvida simples.

Tenho um banco de dados em postgres em que minha variável "datahora" possui valores no formato "AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", como indica a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é em como filtrar valores entre determinados horários (para todos os dias), como por exemplo entre 09:00 e 09:45.

Já fiz os testes com os códigos abaixo (variando o comando ***date_part*** com o ***to_char*** também) mas todos apresentam erros.

Código 1

```
select * from tb_registros
where tick in ('IBOV') 
and date_part(datahora, 'hh:mm:ss') = between 09:00:00 and 09:45:00 
order by datahora desc
```

Código 2

```
select * from tb_registros
where tick in ('IBOV') 
and date_part(datahora, 'hh:mm:ss') >= 09:00:00 and <= 09:45:00 
order by datahora desc
```

Código 3

```
select * from tb_registros
where tick in ('IBOV') 
and date_part(datahora, 'hh:mm:ss') >= 09:00:00 and date_part(datahora, 'hh:mm:ss') <= 09:45:00 
order by datahora desc
```

Alguém consegue me auxiliar?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: "mas todos apresentam erros." , quais ? Creio que a comparação deva ser com string ... 'hh:mm:ss') >= '09:00:00' ...

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho utilizar [extract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) ao invés de `date_part`, ambas fazem a mesma coisa, sendo que a primeira faz parte do padrão sql ansi (American National Standards Institute), sendo comum aos demais bancos de dados e a segunda sendo exclusiva do Postgresql, talvez algum outro sgbd tenha implementado, mas teria que pesquisar.

Relacionado ao problema específico, basta extrair a hora e extrair os minutos e comparar conforme consulta abaixo.

```
select * from tb_registros
where tick in ('IBOV') 
    and extract(hour from datahora) = 9
    and extract(minute from datahora) <= 45
order by datahora desc
```

De qualquer forma, você está usando o date_part de forma equivocada, a maneira correta é: `date_part(text, timestamp)`.

Segue abaixo uma solução com date_part.

```
select * from tb_registros
where tick in ('IBOV') 
    and date_part('hour', datahora) = 9
    and date_part('minute', datahora) <= 45
order by datahora desc
```

Comment: E o perguntador some ...